# How to read UIDs from firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

With granted permission, how to read these UIDs? I have tried this with no luck:

```
//members.ts

    export class MembersPage {
      user:any = 'wait...';

      constructor() {
        firebase.database().ref('Accounts').once('value', function(mySnap){
            mySnap.forEach(function(uiDSnapshot) {
            this.user = uiDSnapshot.key;
            console.log(this.user);
            }); 
        });
    }
```

[image]

```
//members.html
{{user}}
```

Comment: is `console.log(uiDSnapshot)` getting result?

Comment: <unavailable> thrice. I guess they are keys

Comment: no you should get an object there

Comment: check you are pointed to correct firebase reference.

Comment: `console.log(uiDSnapshot.key)` works but `this.user` doesn't. Maybe i have to write it before passing to a variable.

Comment: if `this.user` is an array try `this.user.push(uiDSnapshot.key)`

Comment: `export class MembersPage {
  user:any = 'wait...';

  constructor() {....`

Result: `this is undefined`

Comment: Could you add more code in the question?

Comment: I have updated sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the scope in which you are assigning `this.user`. You create a new scope, if you use `function()`, try using [lambdas/arrow functions](https://codeburst.io/javascript-arrow-functions-for-beginners-926947fc0cdc) instead:

**EDIT:**

```
//members.ts

export class MembersPage {
  user: [string] = [];

  constructor() {
    firebase.database().ref('Accounts').once('value', (mySnap) => {
        mySnap.forEach((uiDSnapshot) => {
            this.user.push(uiDSnapshot.key);
            console.log(this.user);
        }); 
    });
}
```

For further information on the scoping problem you might wanna take a look [at this.](https://toddmotto.com/es6-arrow-functions-syntaxes-and-lexical-scoping/#functionality-lexical-scoping-this)

Comment: It returns the last data out of 3 when i pace `{{user}}` in template. Then I tried `<ion-col *ngFor="let tst of user">{{tst.key}}</ion-col>` for the code `this.user = uiDSnapshot` without luck.

Comment: If you want to get **all**, try the following: `user = []` and `this.user.push(uiDSnapshot.key);`, then you can iterate over them with `*ngFor`

Comment: `_this.user is undefined` for `this.user.push(uiDSnapshot.key);`

Comment: That works for `<ion-col *ngFor="let tst of user">{{tst}}</ion-col>`. Problem solved. Thank you Alex